# How to filter name, date from model using segment control in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, filter

I trying data filter data from segment control. I have five segment namely "All", "Req", "Requisitioner", "Total Value", "Date". I tried to filter the values using

```
searchedData.sorted(by: { $0.req! > $1.req! })
```

but does not working.

Here is my static array:

```
  var sampleData = [RequisitionModel(req: "123", requisitioner: "eqqw", totalValue: "4123", dateCreated: "05/7/2022"),
RequisitionModel(req: "1234", requisitioner: "seqw", totalValue: "0123", dateCreated: "20/8/2022"),
RequisitionModel(req: "134", requisitioner: "efqw", totalValue: "56123", dateCreated: "10/5/2022"),
RequisitionModel(req: "3634", requisitioner: "eqw", totalValue: "6123", dateCreated: "20/9/2022"),
RequisitionModel(req: "22234", requisitioner: "deqw", totalValue: "123", dateCreated: "20/10/2022")]
```

Here is my segment control function:

```
     @IBAction func segmentedControlAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    switch segmentFilter.selectedSegmentIndex {

    case 0:
        print("All")
        dataFilter = 0
    case 1:
        print("Req No")
        dataFilter = 1
    case 2:
        print("Requisitioner")
        dataFilter = 2
    case 3:
        print("Total Value")
        dataFilter = 3
    case 4:
        print("Date Created")
        dataFilter = 4

    default:
        print("All")
        dataFilter = 0
    }
    reload()

}

func reload() {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

Here is my tableview function, where i am trying to filter data:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prCell", for: indexPath) as! PrListCellTableViewCell

    var data = searchedData[indexPath.row]


    switch dataFilter {
    case 0:
        tableView.reloadData()
    case 1:

 searchedData = searchedData.sorted(by: { $0.req! > $1.req! })
    case 2:

        searchedData = searchedData.sorted(by: { $0.requisitioner! > $1.requisitioner! })

    case 3:

        data.totalValue = searchedData[indexPath.row].totalValue

    case 4:
        data.dateCreated = searchedData[indexPath.row].dateCreated
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"// yyyy-MM-dd"
        var convertedArray = [Date]()

        for dat in searchedData {

            let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: dat.dateCreated!)

            if let date = date1 {

                convertedArray.append(date)
            }
        }

        let ready = convertedArray.sorted(by: { $0.compare($1) == .orderedDescending })
        print(ready)
    default:

        data = searchedData[indexPath.row]

    }



    print("req|:\(String(describing: data.req))")
    cell.reqLbl.text = data.req
    cell.requisitionerLbl.text = data.requisitioner
    cell.totalValueLbl.text = data.totalValue
    cell.dateCreatedLbl.text = data.dateCreated

    let ChecktapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.checktapBtnAction(_:)))
    cell.tickImageView.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.tickImageView.addGestureRecognizer(ChecktapGesture)
    cell.tickImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let passReqtapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.passReqtapBtnAction(_:)))
    cell.passReqNo.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.passReqNo.addGestureRecognizer(passReqtapGesture)
    cell.passReqNo.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


    return cell
}
```

I could not able filter the data from searchData array. Any help much appreciated pls...

Comment: you need searching data or sorted data ?

Comment: if you need search data then where is string you are trying to search?

Comment: @AbuUlHassan i'm trying sort data based on date, req no, requisitioner and totalvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove switch conditions from cellForRow method and add it in segmentedControl action method 
like below  and see th magic

```
    var sampleData = [RequisitionModel(req: "123", requisitioner: "eqqw", totalValue: "4123", dateCreated: "05/7/2022"),
        RequisitionModel(req: "1234", requisitioner: "seqw", totalValue: "0123", dateCreated: "20/8/2022"),
        RequisitionModel(req: "134", requisitioner: "efqw", totalValue: "56123", dateCreated: "10/5/2022"),
        RequisitionModel(req: "3634", requisitioner: "eqw", totalValue: "6123", dateCreated: "20/9/2022"),
        RequisitionModel(req: "22234", requisitioner: "deqw", totalValue: "123", dateCreated: "20/10/2022")]



       @IBAction func segmentedControlAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    switch segmentFilter.selectedSegmentIndex {

     case 0:
      searchData = sampleData
break
    case 1:

 searchedData = searchedData.sorted(by: { $0.req! > $1.req! })
    case 2:    
        searchedData = searchedData.sorted(by: { $0.requisitioner! > $1.requisitioner! })
break

    case 3:

        searchedData = { $0. totalValue! > $1. totalValue! }

    break
    case 4:
        data.dateCreated = searchedData[indexPath.row].dateCreated
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"// yyyy-MM-dd"
let searchedData = searchedData r.sorted { dateFormatter.date(from: $0. dateCreated!)! > dateFormatter.date(from: $1. dateCreated!)! }

        print(ready)
break
    default:
searchData = sampleData
} 
 tableView.reloadData()
}
unc tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prCell", for: indexPath) as! PrListCellTableViewCell

var data = searchedData[indexPath.row]
print("req|:\(String(describing: data.req))")
cell.reqLbl.text = data.req
cell.requisitionerLbl.text = data.requisitioner
cell.totalValueLbl.text = data.totalValue
cell.dateCreatedLbl.text = data.dateCreated

let ChecktapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.checktapBtnAction(_:)))
cell.tickImageView.tag = indexPath.row
cell.tickImageView.addGestureRecognizer(ChecktapGesture)
cell.tickImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

let passReqtapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.passReqtapBtnAction(_:)))
cell.passReqNo.tag = indexPath.row
cell.passReqNo.addGestureRecognizer(passReqtapGesture)
cell.passReqNo.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
return cell
}
```

Comment: in segmentedControl Action i dont have data.totalValue = searchedData[indexPath.row].totalValue indexpath.

Comment: it shows error Instance member 'row' cannot be used on type 'IndexPath'